# Living / Linked Copy of File without Alias

Tags: file, symlink, google-apps

Is it possible to have a linked copy of a file that updates whenever the original is saved?

This is mainly for use with Google Drive and SVN, where I need a file to exist in two locations, but not be aliases.

Comment: Does it have to be a linked copy?  I do roughly the same thing, but with OneDrive.  I just save directly to the OneDrive directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **hard link** with `ln` in Terminal. A hard link points to the file inode rather than the file location as with a symlink.

```
$ touch foo.txt
$ echo "this is foo" > foo.txt
$ ln foo.txt hardlink
$ cat hardlink
this is foo
$ mkdir bar
$ mv foo.txt bar
$ cat hardlink
this is foo
```

More on symbolic links vs hard links: https://askubuntu.com/q/108771/562767

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. Good trick to know. Thanks. :D